# Send commands to Google's Console using Python 3

Tags: python, google-chrome

I'm trying to send a command to Google's console using Python 3.

Could someone locate me to a Python extension capable of doing such things?

Comment: what console ? Do you mean page Google Search Console: https://search.google.com/search-console ? You can use Selenium to control web browser and work with any page. But Google mostly has some API to work with its services: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/

Comment: when you inspect a element, or press F12. That console. I don't know what it's called to be honest.